# Runtime of string concatenation checking algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, runtime

I wrote an algorithm to check whether or not a string is a concatenation of any number of strings in an array (while being able to use a string multiple times). I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what the runtime of the algorithm is.

I check the string in question against every word in the array and when I find a word that is a substring of the original string starting at index 0, I check the remaining substring against every word in the array as well. So I'm thinking this is an O(n^n), unless I'm missing something.

```
def check_concat(str,substr,words)
  if substr == ""
    return false
  end

  words.each do |word|
    if word == substr && str != substr
      return true
    end
    if substr.index(word) == 0
      if check_concat(str,substr[word.length..-1],words)
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, should the complexity of this not be expressed in terms of both the length of the input string (say, m) *and* the size of the array (n)?

Comment: I see, hadn't considered that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume your main string contains `m words` and there are `n words` in the array to be searched. In the worst case you need to check each word in the main string with each word in the array, which is `mn` time. Thus the time complexity of the function is `O(mn)`.

For example the main string be `"Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello"`. The array to be checked contains the following words `'Hai', 'Fine', 'Hello'`. Then the function will require a total of 15 comparisons.

Comment: That example definitely makes it easier to think about, thanks!